# Flex items evenly spaced but first item aligned left

Tags: css, flexbox

Flexbox's `justify-content: space-around` makes my list items horizontally evenly spaced. Is there a way to have exactly the same thing with the only difference that the first item on the left has no space on its left? (that is, the list "starts" from the left edge of the container)

Comment: If this layout is what you're intending to do, it makes no sense to use any of the `space-*` property, because it will evenly distribute all the space in between. If you want to remove the spacing on the left-most item, how do you want the rest of the space to be distributed? This is another question that you will need to ask yourself. Should the remaining space be total width minus the calculated left spacing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `justify-content: space-between`, but the last content will have also no space on the right.

A good [documentation](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: One strategy using space-between: Add a blank div on the end; this will solve the problem of no space on the right side.

Answer (score 48):

Instead of using `justify-content: space-around`, use `auto` margins on the items.

By giving each flex item `margin-right: auto`, container space will be distributed evenly between items (like `justify-content`), but the first item will remain at the left border edge.

```css
flex-container[one] {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: 1px dashed green;
}

flex-container[one]>flex-item {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

flex-container[two] {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

flex-container[two]>flex-item {
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: orangered;
}

flex-item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<code>justify-content: space-around</code>
<flex-container one>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
</flex-container>

<br>

<code>margin-right: auto</code>
<flex-container two>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
</flex-container>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/t5yzknxe/)

Learn more about flex `auto` margins here: [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Comment: Genius, simply genius!

Comment: Good stuff.  I applied the same principle to a vertical layout using `justify-content: space evenly` with `margin-top: auto` to get the items to stick to the bottom and maintain responsive, even spacing.  The gap property just won't work for all screen sizes, and it beats having to write a special rule with a magic number along 5 media queries (which flexbox is supposed to solve!).

Comment: this is such a great answer I had comment. Simple, explanatory and concise, great work.

Answer (score 4):

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.container .item {
    margin: 0 auto 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">Apple</div>
    <div class="item">Orange</div>
    <div class="item">Pineapple</div>
</div>
```

Using `auto` for `margin-right` items will be "forced" to left.

Answer (score 3):

Another way :

- Create a "splitter" element with the css attribute `flex-grow: 1`.
- Add the CSS attribute `display: flex` to the wrapper panel.
- Add the splitters where you need them

Short example below, the splitter elements are marked in red

```css
.main
{
  display: flex;
  
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.element
{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.splitter
{
  flex-grow: 1;
    
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="element">
  </div>
  <div class="element">
  </div>

  <div class="splitter">
  
  </div>

  <div class="element">
  </div>

  <div class="splitter">
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="element">
  </div>
  <div class="splitter">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice idea! Used this to override non-fully supported "justify-content: space-evenly" on Microsoft Edge 18

Answer (score 0):

Use `justify-content: space-between` instead of `space-around` to get what you are trying to achieve here.

Refer code:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
  <li>Mango</li>
  <li>Pineapple</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I appreciate the time you spend on your answer, but Shiva answered first so I accepted his/her answer.